# Minimum four Sum Subsequence

Tags: algorithm, dynamic

Can anyone suggest the idea of how to find minimum sum subsequence from the array such that at least one value among all groups of four consecutive elements is picked in an array of positive integers? 
 [Question here](https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/minimum-four-sum-subsequence/1)
I guess the answer on geeksforgeeks doesn't provide the correct answer to test case (1,2,3,3,4,5,6,3) whose output should be 3 according to me. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: They consider each value to be unique, the number they represent may have repeats, but they are "different". With your interpretation, it would be a different problem. Note that they must pick 1 element every 4 numbers, while you dont

Comment: I got it. Thanks a lot sir. Sorry for the wrong interpretation. But it means my previous interpretation would require a try and hit approach?

Comment: With your interpretation, I think it can be reduced to Minimum Weighted Vertex Cover which is NP hard

Comment: I will check it out. Thanks a lot sir .